# How to put text inside triangle button?

Tags: html, css

I create triangle button at header of my page, and i would like to put text in button.

Now text is outside button.

My code:

```css
.collapsible {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
}

.triangle {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000;
    width: 190px;
    height: 140px;
    border-top: solid 140px #2b2b2b;
    border-left: solid 140px transparent;
    border-right: solid 140px transparent;
    border-bottom: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible triangle" id="collapse">Some content</button>
```

So as u can see text is outside of buuton, how it's possible to set inside button?

Comment: in 2019, we should no more use border to create triangles: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696143/8620333 and see the bottom answers to find the good ways like background, clip-path, svg, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.collapsible {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
}

.triangle {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000;
    width: 190px;
    height: 140px;
    border-top: solid 140px #2b2b2b;
    border-left: solid 140px transparent;
    border-right: solid 140px transparent;
    border-bottom: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.collapsible span{
    position: absolute;
    color:red;
    top:-120px;
    left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible triangle" id="collapse">
<span>Some content</span></button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this. The only problem is that the triangle is black and the inside text is black too. You should change the triangle color instead to see the text.

`<button class="collapsible triangle" id="collapse" value="Some content"></button>`

Comment: Not working, i change text color